# Git The Last Commit Date from a GitHub Link using Github API

Tags: github-api

I Have a specific Link that refer to a repo :

```
https://github.com/winkbrace/verlanglijstjes/blob/3d2ad6485254bb1fef52321248beab71103645f9/database/dump/verlanglijstjes.sql
```

The last commit was done on 27-Feb-2022

How can i get the last commit date using GitHub API syntax?

Answer (score 0):

It can depend if you want the most recent commit from all the branches or only the default branch.

And if, by last commit date, you mean committer date, not author date.

In any case, start by [installing GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/manual/installation), and:

For the main branch:

```
gh api repos/git/git/commits/HEAD/branches-where-head --jq .[].commit.url
gh api repos/git/git/commits/715d08a9e51251ad8290b181b6ac3b9e1f9719d7 --jq .commit.committer.date
2022-02-25T23:47:38Z
```

In your case:

```sh
gh api repos/winkbrace/verlanglijstjes/commits/HEAD/branches-where-head --jq .[0].commit.url
https://api.github.com/repos/winkbrace/verlanglijstjes/commits/ccb174356ca35ace51dbaa2c34592b371b671436
```

And:

```sh
gh api repos/winkbrace/verlanglijstjes/commits/ccb174356ca35ace51dbaa2c34592b371b671436 --jq .commit.committer.date
2022-03-05T13:21:42Z
```

Comment: If you need to iterate on branches, see as a related example https://gist.github.com/jimmybish/cf4ab5494f9f9d2e032ae44906a2928e